# Forcing Debezium SQL Server connector to create topic for empty table

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I am using a Debezium source connector to ingest data from tables under a SQL Server instance, and them publishing the data to a Kafka instance (and the respective schemas to a Schema Registry).

The problem I am aiming to solve is that while Kafka Connect and Debezium run fine, ingest the data and create the topics and the Avro schemas for SQL Server tables that are populated, the same is not true for empty tables (both created and non-created topics have their respective tables mapped at the `table.include.list` property).

This would be useful in my context because after setting up the connectors, I run a ksqlDB initialization process that relies on these topics (and the respective schemas) already being present.

The target Kafka instance has topic auto-creation turned off (*auto.create.topics.enable=false*), so I have turned Kafka Connect topic auto-creation on, through the property `CONNECT_TOPIC_CREATION_ENABLE: "true"` plus the setup of topic properties in the connectors, like:

```
"topic.creation.default.replication.factor": 2,
"topic.creation.default.partitions": 2,
"topic.creation.default.cleanup.policy": "compact",
"topic.creation.default.compression.type": "lz4"
```

The target Schema Registry is also correctly mapped under the `CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL` property from Kafka Connect.

Is there any way to force the SQL Server Debezium source connector to trigger topic creation for empty tables?

I am using Kafka Connect 7.3.0 and Debezium SQL Server Connector 1.9.7.

Comment: Why can't you pre-create the topics on your own? Schemas can be added to the registry after topics exist.